# Cannot use the package "openexr" in python within Blender

Tags: python, blender

I've installed the "openexr" package within my windows system. To do this, i used powershell from my blender installation folder "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python" to launch the command ".\bin\python.exe -m ensurepip", for installing pip, and then "pip install openexer" to install the package.

Everything seems fine, but when I open blender and start to code with a simple

import openexr

I obtain this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openexr'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

The module seems installed, but it's like blender cannot access it. Someone can help me? I would be extremely happy if this could work !

At the moment I tried to re-install pip or the openexr package, but the problem persist.
Also, if I try to re-install openexr, the system answer me that the package is already installed.

Comment: No, you have to install it in /site-packages, means globally `pip3 install openexr`. Then restart your terminal session.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very fresh about these topics, may I ask how can I do it?

Comment: Open PowerShell, run command `pip install openexr`, close after completion. Then try.